# PHP while loop fill shop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently making a personal website & forums (That'll remain personal for a while)

By posting helpful threads or answering questions frequently users will be granted "Reputation points"

The end goal is to have these "Reputation points" as a spendable currency on the site, enabling the ability to purchase entry into elite forum sections, coloured username text, etc.

---

But right now I'm on the basics of FILLING the shop with the products.

I'm connected to my database, and have access to the tables within it (I can print out the data contains in the rows with the following php after connection has been established):

```
<?php
// Fill shop
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row["Product Name"]." ".$row["Price"]."<br />";
}
?>
```

However, what I'd like to do is integrate some html and use my item class (in CSS) for how a shop item should be formatted.

Keep in mind, that this code below doesn't work, but it's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<div class="item">
    <h3><?php $row["Product Name"] ?></h3>
    <img src="<?php $row["ProductImagePath"]?>"/><br />
    <?php $row["Product Price"] ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Buy" />
    </form>
</div>
```

So, instead of just listing the data, it instead places it into an item and generates a new item (one per product found)

Any idea how I'd achieve this?

Thanks, would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: So you would like to create an item class and for every item found in the database create an item instance from the class?

Comment: How does it look like placing *"it into an item"* and how does the generation of such item (you generate it *after* you have created it as you place it into????) look like? I really have problems to understand your question.

Comment: I have the CSS to make an "item" already (<Div class ="item">), I've already defined what it should LOOK like. what I'm trying to do is make an item APPEAR on the page USING this CSS for every product it finds in my products table.

So, if it finds 10 products in my products table, I want it to generate 10 items using the CSS I've created.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To print out the items in html you can just use the same `foreach` you have above and print out the items by `echo`ing out their values:

```
<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <div class="item">
        <h3><?php echo $row["Product Name"] ?></h3>
        <img src="<?php echo $row["ProductImagePath"]?>"/><br />
        <?php echo $row["Product Price"] ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Buy" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

where basically what you were missiing are the actual `echo` statements to output the values into the `html` source

Comment: What's up with those downvotes? Care to explain or just clicking randomly?

Comment: I have no idea, you're post is fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is just fine except for one thing: add an `echo` in front of every `$row[...]`. Right now you are just calling the rows without echoing them.

It would look like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <h3><?php echo $row["Product Name"]; ?></h3>
    <img src="<?php echo $row["ProductImagePath"]; ?>"/><br />
    <?php echo $row["Product Price"]; ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Buy" />
    </form>
</div>
```